# terminal: "npm install -g react-native-cli"

Tags: macos, npm

```
npm install -g react-native-cli

npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/qufenqi/.npm/react-native-     cli/0.1.4/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "react-native-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
 npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
```

npm ERR! errno -13

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-      cli']
 npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:35:25',
npm ERR!            '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:47:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with a
```

but when i install node,say
" brew install node
Warning: node-0.12.7 already installed, it's just not linked"

Comment: Please, explain yourself a bit better. What OS are you using, what are you trying to achieve, etc... The title for the question is horrible anyway.

Answer (score 10):

You don't have write access to the directory

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli
```

As you're going to install the library globally, you need admin permissions, so do that as *root* using *sudo* command:

```
sudo npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Comment: I got "node: No such file or directory"

Comment: Then you don't have node installed or your path to NodeJS is not properly set up.

Comment: Idk why they don't just make a dmg file as installer.

Answer (score 2):

if the error persists and showing you that the symlink is already exists

```
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/react-native'
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/react-native
```

add `--force`

```
sudo npm install -g react-native-cli --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `brew doctor`

i'll bet that node will show as an "unlinked keg in your cellar"

If thats the case run `brew link node`

it may fail, but it will give you some options on what you can do such as overwrite or the directory it's trying to write too.

If that doesn't work you may just want to `brew uninstall node` and reinstall it

Answer (score 0):

without sudo works.

```
 npm i -g  @react-native-community/cli --force
```

then check,

```
npm list @react-native-community/cli
```